# I want to make a app with c code without using NDK or JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Hi friends i want to make a Android app with c code. it cannot use NDK and JNI and that app should run on non rooted mobile. is there any possible please help me thank you in advance

Comment: It's not possible without severe limitations

Comment: lol forget it...

Comment: .oOo. Use JNA :) .oOo.

Comment: @mko JNA uses JNI internally.

Comment: ..oOo.  ;)  .oOo..

Comment: JNI is the way to use C in Java. Where is your limitation coming from? Why can't it use NDK and JNI?

Comment: @velpukonda Ramesh Hii . Did you get the solution to this question? Please reply me